# App bar title not displaying in android 5.0 and above

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design

Hi i have created a simple application and tested it on android 4.4.4 and above

in 4.4.4 Kitkat - it works fine (I can see the title in the app bar)

[image]

But when i test it on android 5.0 and above, the title is invisible

[image]

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>


    <style name="myCustomAppBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <!--*************************    Custom Theme  *******************************  -->
    <style name="myCustomAppBarTheme_old" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
        <item name="android:height">100dp</item>
        <item name="height">100dp</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    </style>


    <!--****************************  Custom Theme  *******************************  -->



    <!--****************************  Switch Theme  *******************************  -->
    <style name="SCBSwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

        <!-- inactive thumb color -->
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#f1f1f1
        </item>

        <!-- inactive track color (30% transparency) -->
        <item name="android:colorForeground">#42221f1f
        </item>
    </style>
    <!--****************************  Switch Theme  *******************************  -->

</resources>
```

**Dashboard.xml Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/act_layou_dash_main"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <!-- Include Appbar -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_dashboard"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_dashboard" />

    <!-- include Shadow below appbar -->
    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativemain_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_tickets"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

        </RelativeLayout>



        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout = "@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:name="baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskticketsystem.Data.navigationDrawerFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**App Bar dashboard**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    app:theme="@style/myCustomAppBarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**DashBoard class**

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ListView drawerList;
    private navigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment;
    List<TicketsItemObject> items = new ArrayList<TicketsItemObject>();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private TicketsRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Dashboard");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        applicationEnvironment = new ApplicationEnvironmentURL(this.context);
        context = this.getApplicationContext();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_dashboard);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        drawerFragment = (navigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="baman.lankahomes.lk">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Signup" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPassword"
            android:label="@string/forgotpass" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CompanyProfile"
            android:label="@string/your_company_profile" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Dashboard"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity
            android:name=".NewTicket"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity android:name=".Tickets" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TicketDetails"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TicketResponse"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AddNote"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity android:name=".Notifications"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" ></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try to change color of textview from white to any other !

Comment: check your values-21/style.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your title");
```

Comment: Hy tnx. but am getting the error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskticketsystem/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskticketsystem.Dashboard}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: make sure in activity you have imported: "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar"? AppTheme you can try to set strenghtly to 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set title after you call:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and then use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");
```

as a setting title method.

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but with a different source affecting any version. Calls to `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");` did not work for me as in my layout I had nested within my `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` a `<RelativeLayout>` for some positioning. It appears that inserting your own nested layout in a Toolbar replaces whatever the default layout container is, and therefore removes the default title view as well.

So if I wanted to use that layout I'd have to supply and set my own `TextView` that uses or overrides `style="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"` as well. In the end it turned out I didn't need my own nested layout; I could just use `android:layout_gravity` and some margin tweaking to position my custom views within the `Toolbar`.